# Backbone and Require.js not finding certain modules at specific level of defines

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a limit to the number of dependencies Require.js will validly call? I'm getting strange 404 errors that I can't seem to debug.

I have the following structure:

```
-js
--views
---guide
----chapter.js
----guide.js
----section.js
----sidebar.js
```

In my router.js file, I do:

```
define([

    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'views/guide/guide'
], function(_, Backbone, guideView) { 
});
```

In guide.js:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    './sidebar',
], function(_, Backbone, sidebarView) {
});
```

In sidebar.js:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'jquery',
    'easing',
    'audiojs',
    'markdown',

    './chapter'
], function(_, Backbone, $, easing, audiojs, markdown, chapterView) {
});
```

Finally, in chapter.js:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'jquery',
    'easing',
    'audiojs',
    'markdown',

    './section.js',

    'lib/text!templates/guide/chapter.html',
], function(_, Backbone, $, easing, audiojs, markdown , sectionView, template) {
});
```

For the LAST one, I get a 404 error:

```
http://localhost/testapp/views/guide/section.js?bust=1372855006799
```

It seems to be dropping 'js' from the file path and I have no idea why, unless there's some limit to how many levels of dependency I can call, or something like that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use the .js in your paths, require knows that you are trying to load javascriptfiles so there is not need to put them. try removing the .js

```
 './section',
```

and also I think you have an extra comma at the end of the template definition as is the last one.

```
 'lib/text!templates/guide/chapter.html'
```

And I dont think there is a limit on the levels of dependency.

Comment: Holy god you gotta be kidding me. I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out, that fixed it. GUUUHH